# JavaScript and Submitting Data in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a set button before the user submits a registration, where I need to set html before the server submits the php code. However, I cannot seem to get this working, any suggestions? I;am using typeahead.js for the input. (Full Name works perfectly)

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
   <div>
 <?php $full_name = 'akID[' . UserAttributeKey::getByHandle('full_name')->getAttributeKeyID() . '][value]'; ?>
        <?php echo $form->label($full_name, t('Full Name')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->text($full_name); ?>
   </div>
   <br/>
<form id="school" onclick="doThis()">
<?php $school = 'akID[' . UserAttributeKey::getByHandle('school')->getAttributeKeyID() . '][value]; ?>]'; ?>
   <?php echo $form->label($school, t('Please Select your School from the Dropdown Box.') )?><br/>
    <input type=text id="school" name="school" class="form-control typeahead" value="Enter Your School ">
      <input type="button" value="Set" onsubmit="setSchool();"/>
</form>


<script>
function setSchool()
{
 var school = $("#school").val();
 $school = $_POST(school);
}
</script>


</div>
</form>
```

Comment: php and javascript run in different environments and at different times. Stop mixing them as if they can talk to each other.

Comment: @charlietfl I understand that, I was just trying to include javascript in concrete5's registration process. I have managed to get it working by simply duplicating the typeahead,js into a hidden input

Comment: that's fine but `setSchool()` will only accept javascript code when it is being run in the browser

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the same id for form and input. Change or remove id attribute from school input, add `method='post'` to the form and change your function setSchool to:

```
function setSchool()
$('input[name="school"]).val("<?php echo json_encode($_POST["school"]); ?>");
 $("#school").submit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, here is the code

'code'
<script>
function setSchool()
{
 $("#school").submit();
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="Set" onsubmit="setSchool()"/>

However, still cant get it to post like full_name which works, any ideas?

Comment: is it possible to get the value forced into this, like the full_name?

<?php echo $form->text($full_name); ?>

Maybe as a hidden input, this will work for what im trying I think

Comment: to fill this input you can use setSchool from my updated answer or use php to fill it as you did with full_name.

Comment: It doesnt like the syntax of this

function setSchool()
{
 $('input[name="school"]).val('<?php echo $_POST["school"]; ?>')
}
</script>

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /var/sites/v//public_html/single_pages/register.php on line 101